# What is he saying in video?

Tags: spoken-english

What is he saying between 1:55 ~ 2:00 in the video in the link below? I can't hear well...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=koJMqQ5pV6E&feature=youtu.be&t=115

Comment: *"It seems that every age(?) falls for a tenor, and falls hard."* It means that tenors are more popular and loved in any musical era.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ELL is not a transcription service. See [this post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3371/please-suggest-a-good-web-site-where-i-can-ask-what-is-said-in-a-short-part-of-a) for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Andrew that the narrator says "It seems that every age falls for a tenor, and falls hard," but I disagree with his interpretation. I'd say this means that during each historical period, there is seemingly one tenor singer who wins vast popular acclaim. It could be that, for instance, baritones are more popular as a class, but at any time there are a number of popular baritones and not one who stands out as the absolute greatest.

"The age" (the people of the age) "falls for" (fall in love with, develop a unique passion for) "a tenor" (one, over and above all others) "and falls hard" (and this love is intense and singular).

It's saying that at any given time there is just one tenor singer who is unquestionably the most deeply loved by the public.